# can I work with Microsoft Commerce server, catalog API , with Windows Service Application

Tags: commerce, microsoft-commerce-server

I worked before with "Microsoft Commerce server 2007" and used it's Catalog API to get products data in my web site.
But I have a requirement to make a windows service that uses the commerce product catalog data, but I don't know how to adjust the APP.Config of this service to get data.

Every time I try commerce code it returns Null "CommerceContext.Current"== null

any Idea or sample config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `CatalogContext` object in Local or Agent mode.  See [How to Create a CatalogContext Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms944262%28v=cs.70%29.aspx) for details.

`CommerceContext.Current` is only non-null when running in the context of an ASP.NET web application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, it's working with me , I understand now; I don't need the "CommerceContext.Current" in web service , I need only "CatalogContext" and for it I can get any product data I need.